# OpenLayers ::: Counting the houses in a polygon?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, dictionary, geolocation, openlayers

I need to be able to count all the houses/addresses that exist inside a polygon. I've thought it through and it seems possible to find if a single address exists inside a polygon (by finding if the geolocation intersects with it?)

Is it possible to pull a list of all the addresses in an area and check if they intersect? Or might there be some other method?

Answer (score 0):

If I were to try to do this on the browser client, I would get an array of OpenLayers.LonLat objects or OpenLayers.Geometry.Point objects.  I would iterate over that array and ask if each object was within a polygon by calling the containsPoint function of OpenLayers.Geometry.Polygon.  I would count or collect the points that fall within the polygon.

Geospatial operations like you are describing are something we do on the server using open source GeoTools.  We tend to use OpenLayers almost exclusively for map visualization.

I may have not answered your question entirely because I sense you are trying to get that list of addresses/points in the first place for an area on the map, and I don't think you've provided enough information to answer that part of the question.